# How to generate an new Array using a return from another function? Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

So im trying to make a color guessing game
So i created a function that generates a color and returns it, which works fine
But since i have 3 buttons with #hex code on them 1 button has to be a correct answer and correct #hex has to be displayed in a color box

So im trying to put 3 #hex codes in each button and choose randomly which #hex code is the correct one and display it in HTML

i know the code is very bad but i still got a long way to go...

```
function randomColor(){
    let randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
    return randomColor
}

function arrayOfColors(){
    let randColorArr = []
}
function generateColors(){    
    colorBox.style.backgroundColor = `#${correctColor}`
    btn.forEach(button => button.innerHTML = `#${randomColor()}`)
}
generateColors()
```

Comment: I noticed a bug in your code: `randomColor` will generate invalid colors (with a length other than 6 or 3) with a ~6% chance. You are missing `.padStart(6, '0')` in your color generation. Also, it will never be able to generate `ffffff` because you used `16777215` as _exclusive_ upper bound instead of `16777216` (which would have been easier to understand in my opinion as `0x1000000` or `1 << 24` or `2 ** 24` by the way)

Comment: @CherryDT yeah that's minor that can be fixed later and thats the least of my worries, have to code this thing first which is turning to be a major headache and is part of my homework so to say

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`randomColor` - I made a correction to your function that will always return a valid color number,

`arrayOfColors` - I answered your question about the function and it now returns an array with three colors for your three buttons,

`randomIntFromInterval` - designed to generate numbers in a certain range that you determine,

`generateColors` -

1. I drew an array of three colors,
2. I drew a lottery for the position in the array that would be the correct color,
3. I gave the div the correct color, and the buttons all three colors including a click event that will check if the user won,
4. Immediately after clicking, a new game starts.

```js
const colorBox = document.querySelector('div');
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('button');

function randomColor(){
let randomColor = `#${Math.floor(Math.random() * 0x1000000).toString(16).padStart(6, '0')}`;
    return randomColor
}

function arrayOfColors(){
    const arrayOfColors = [...Array(3).keys()].map(() => randomColor());
    return arrayOfColors;
}

function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) { // min and max included    
return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min) 
};

function generateColors(){  
    const  arr = arrayOfColors();
    const correctIndexColor = randomIntFromInterval(0, 2);
    colorBox.style.backgroundColor = `${arr[correctIndexColor]}`;
    btns.forEach((button, index) => {
        button.innerHTML = `${arr[index]}`;
        button.onclick = () => {
           if(index === correctIndexColor)
              alert('win');
           else
              alert('faild');
           generateColors();
        }
    });
}

generateColors()
```

```css
div {
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<button></button>
<button></button>
<button></button>
<div></div>
```

Comment: What do function arrayOfColors() and function randomIntFromInterval do?

Comment: @CrveniFlash I just edited my answer with an explanation for everything, can you read and tell me if something is still not clear to you?

Comment: many things but its alright this program was way above my pay-grade right now as i realized by reading your solution, thought it was much simpler then this, that you very much for the help!!

Comment: Instead of the awkward calculation and slicing which a) creates an uneven random distribution and is unable to produce colors like `00ff00` and b) sometimes creates invalid colors such as `f04a1.` or `efe5.3`, I recommend simply using `Math.floor(Math.random() * 0x1000000).toString(16).padStart(6, '0')` - it is easy to read and understand, very straight-forward in its intentions and covers all colors from `000000` to `ffffff` (and with equal probability for each)

Comment: It's still not right (now it has the same issues but worse because the probability for encountering a dot is higher), it would need `Math.floor` to prevent decimals and `padStart` to add leading zeroes - see the code in my comment. What it does is: It creates a random number 0 to 0.9999999..., multiplies that to get instead a random number 0 to 0xffffff.fffffffffff... (= 16777215.9999...), then cuts off decimals to get a random _integer_ number 0 to 0xffffff, then converts to hex string, then pads with enough zeroes at the start to always fill 6 characters.

Comment: @CherryDT Really appreciate your vigilance, I corrected

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the need to declare a `arrayOfColors` function, when you can just generate a random number between 1 and 3 and assign `correctColor` to the relative button:

```js
const btn = document.querySelectorAll('button')
const colorBox = document.getElementById('cbox')

function randomColor(){
    let randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
    return randomColor
}

function generateColors(correctColor){    
    colorBox.style.backgroundColor = `#${correctColor}`
    
    btn.forEach(button => button.innerHTML = `#${randomColor()}`)
    
    // GET RANDOM NUMBER BETWEEN 1 AND 3
    const rndBtnIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (3 - 1 + 1) + 1)
    
    // ASSIGN THE CORRECT COLOR TO RANDOM BUTTON
    document.querySelector('#btn' + rndBtnIndex).innerHTML = `#${correctColor}`
}

generateColors('ff0000')
```

```html
<button id="btn1"></button>
<button id="btn2"></button>
<button id="btn3"></button>

<div id="cbox">
  <p>colorBox</p>
</div>
```